# Jquery fold effect not working for asp.net controls?

Tags: jquery

In asp.net, i am trying to do fold effect on div using asp.net button control but it is not working. instead of asp.net button when i put html controls the effect working fine. can any body help me why it is not working.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#hide").click(function(){
     $(".target").hide( "fold", 
                 {horizFirst: true }, 2000 );
  });

  $("#show").click(function(){
     $(".target").show( "fold", 
                  {horizFirst: true}, 2000 );
  });

});
</script>

the code for buttons goes here

 <asp:Button ID ="show" runat ="server" Text ="Show" />  
 <asp:Button ID ="hide" runat ="server" Text ="hide" />
```

html controls

```
<input type ="button" id ="show" value ="Show" runat ="server" title ="Show" />
<input type ="button" id ="hide" runat ="server"  title ="Hide" value ="Hide" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Server control ids can change if they are not static, so you have to give the **[client ids](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)** which will be generated by asp.net. You can user controlID.ClientID for getting the client id.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#<%= hide.ClientID %>").click(function(){
     $(".target").hide( "fold", 
                 {horizFirst: true }, 2000 );
  });

  $("#<%= show.ClientID %>").click(function(){
     $(".target").show( "fold", 
                  {horizFirst: true}, 2000 );
  });

});
</script>
```

Comment: Put alert in events and check if they are fired?

Comment: yeah i will check and inform you